# WordPress Tools import failed downloading the installation package

Tags: wordpress

I tried to download a package via Tools > Import, and then underneath the WordPress I clicked the "Install Now" link, but it gave me error messages like these:

```
Downloading installation package from https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/wordpress-importer.0.8.zip&#8230;
updates.min.js?ver=6.0.2:2 The authenticity of wordpress-importer.0.8.zip could not be verified as no signature was found.
updates.min.js?ver=6.0.2:2 Unpacking the package&#8230;
updates.min.js?ver=6.0.2:2 Could not copy file. wordpress-importer/class-wp-import.php
```

To better understand it, see the image here: [image: image here]

if you notice it there are strange characters &#8230 at the end of the filename.

Does anyone know why it happens?

Comment: `&#8230` is a **horizontal ellipsis** that is beind used in that notice message. So `&#8230` is not the issue. By reading your error message it looks like, there are issues with file/dir permissions which not allowing the read/write option in the file system. You can turn your debugging and check your file/dir permission and start troubleshooting the issue.

Comment: I've turned on the debugging, but the log doesn't mention any file/dir permission issues.

Comment: However it gives me these messages:
[27-Dec-2022 13:50:11 UTC] PHP Warning:  array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, bool given in /var/www/html/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-upgrader.php on line 500
[27-Dec-2022 13:50:11 UTC] PHP Warning:  count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in /var/www/html/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-upgrader.php on line 504
[27-Dec-2022 13:50:11 UTC] PHP Warning:  count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in /var/www/html/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-upgrader.php on line 507